# If there a way to tell if C++ compiler actually inline a function or not?

Tags: c++, inline

I just wonder if there is a way (like see generated assembly code or I do not know) to see if the C++ compiler actually inline a function? Thanks.

Comment: Usually one does that by examining the generated code. Is the code of the function used instead of a "call" instruction?

Comment: See [godbolt.org](http://godbolt.org)

Comment: Why exactly you would like that kind of information? This might change even between compilations of almost the same code.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski i had a case lately where a student thought it was a good idea to decompile the given example program to avoid writing the code himself. The thing was that the compiler inlined a function and he just copied that so he had an empty function and the code of it in place. So maybe some kind of decompiling story?

Comment: @RadosławCybulski, I am not exactly clear on this topic. Here is my thought. You cannot force the compiler to inline a complex function. But when a function is simply enough, the compiler might just inline this function itself. I am thinking of simplify some function to make them inline to get a performance boost. Are you suggesting that the same code, using the same version of compiler, you get different genarated code at different times? For example, this time the function is inline, next time it is not inline? Thanks for your time.

Comment: More or less yes. Logic behind deciding, wherever to inline or not can get complicated. There're thresholds for amount of inlining code and those depends on compiler (and it's version). If you think making simplified functions will improve performance, do this and **measure** results. But don't go like - i'm sure inlining improves performace so i'll force compiler to inline everything.

Answer (score 0):

`inline` is a suggestion, but the compiler has the freedom to actually do it or not. As far as i know there is no way to force the compiler to inline, and I'd say the compiler knows better.

To see if the compiler did it, I can think of two ways:

- Look at the binary output in debug mode and see if there is a call in place
- Add time profiling instructions. If the time decrease when you declare inline, it means the compiler did infact inline it.

Comment: You could have the compiler print the assembly language of the function (that calls the inline function).